# Suppling user defined fold indices to LightGBM's cross validation when the source dataframe has a multiindex

Tags: lightgbm

**Edit:** Reproducible example below

I am supplying a list of "user generated folds" to lgb.cv(folds=).

It's a list of 2-tuples, where the first element contains training indices and the second has testing indices from my dataset.

Each of these single index elements is a 3-tuple taken from the Pandas Multiindex.

I get the following error:

```
File ".../lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 189, in list_to_1d_numpy
    raise TypeError(f"Wrong type({type(data).__name__}) for {name}.\n"
TypeError: Wrong type(list) for used_indices.
It should be list, numpy 1-D array or pandas Series
```

What type of index should I pass into lgb.cv() ? Does it know about the row index type in the original dataframe?

```
import lightgbm as lgb

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "index_1": ["i1", "i2"],
    "index_2": ["j1", "j2"],
    "feature": [1, 2],
    "target": [3, 4]
}).set_index(["index_1", "index_2"])

data = lgb.Dataset(data=df["feature"].to_frame(), label=df["target"])

folds = [
    [("i1", "j1"), ("i2", "j2")],
    [("i1", "j1"), ("i2", "j2")]
]

gbm = lgb.cv(
    params={},  # parameter dict to use
    train_set=data,
    folds=folds,
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example please?

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround is to reset the multiindex and work with an integer index